# How to use Heroku eclipse plugin ? An error encounter

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, heroku

I am using Heroku eclipse plugin to create a Heroku template. Sorry that I am quite a beginner in Heroku and Maven build. I totally don't know how to use Heroku belt tool to build and push the app to server, so I choose eclipse plugin. Now I encounter an error right after I create a Heroku template:

[image]

```
maven-dependency-plugin (goals "copy-dependencies", "unpack") is not supported by m2e.  pom.xml /herokutesting123123    line 48 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

What could be the problem?

One more problem is how am I going to run the program? Which one should I choose below to build? I thought it should work like how am I working with Tomcat, but I cannot find "run on server" function in the list below. How?

[image]

Last problem is how am I going to push the app to the server? I already got the API key after I key in account and password, but I cannot find any function in eclipse to push the app to the server. I thought it work as simple as Google App Engine, one click will do. So, how can I push the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As James mentioned, that is a bug with the Maven Eclipse plugin, but if you want to get rid of the error, you can add an exclusion similar to this in your `pom.xml`'s `pluginManagement` section:

https://github.com/heroku/template-java-jaxrs/commit/1e68c44a4356216d7077738f87ee9b97545d4bb5

As far as your second question, you deploy the app to Heroku via `git push`. See this doc for details how to do that from Eclipse:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-heroku-eclipse#deploying-changes-to-heroku

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore that error.  It's a bug in the Maven Eclipse Plugin.  To run the app from Eclipse, see the webapp-runner instructions:
https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner#running-your-application-in-eclipse